# How to overwrite the mocked data for a module in different test suite in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a scenario where I have to update the mocked response for a module with different set of values in a different test suite in one of my unit test case written in Jest. Here is my test file looks like :

```
// test.spec.js

  jest.mock('../../Service', () => ({
    getState: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      x: 'x',
      y: 'y',
      z: 'z' 
    })
  })

describe('Test suite 1 - with same mocked data for Service', () => ({
   // expected Service.getState() --> { x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z' }
})

describe('Test suite 2 - with different mocked data for Service', () => ({
 // expected Service.getState() --> { a: 'a', b: 'b' } 
})
```

How do I update the mock value for the following module with an another set of values within the 2nd test suite as follows  ?

```
jest.mock('../../Service', () => ({ 
  getState: jest.fn().mockReturnValue ({ 
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  })
})
```

Is it possible to overwrite the mocked values using beforeEach() method in the second test suite ? Can someone let me the right way to handle this scenario ?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
describe('Test suite 1 - with same mocked data for Service', () => ({
   // expected Service.getState() --> { x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z' }
  jest.mock('../../Service', () => ({
    getState: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      x: 'x',
      y: 'y',
      z: 'z' 
    })
  })
})

describe('Test suite 2 - with different mocked data for Service', () => ({
 // expected Service.getState() --> { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
 jest.mock('../../Service', () => ({
    getState: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
    })
  })
})
```

You have to mock the service separately in every test case. Rather then globally in the describe block.

Answer (score 0):

let suppose you have a test file `SomeComponent.jsx` which involves mocking the `../../Service` dependency then this is what you can do:

```
import { Service } from "../../Service";

jest.mock("../../Service", ({
  getState: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("SomeComponent", () => {
  describe('Test suite 1 - with same mocked data for Service', () => {

    it('should expect mock response 1', () => {
      getState.mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          x: 'x',
          y: 'y',
          z: 'z'
        }
      })
      expect(Service.getState()).toEqual({x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z'});

    });
  });

  describe('Test suite 2 - with different mocked data for Service', () => {

    it('should expect mock response 2', () => {
      getState.mockImplementation(() => {
        return {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
      })
      expect(Service.getState()).toEqual({a: 'a', b: 'b'});

    });
  });
});
```

You want to test both objects of getState, so you use mockReturnValueOnce to make the mock function return object1 in the first invocation, and object2 in the second one.

You import the mocked module in your case its `import {Service} from "../../Service"`; to gain access to the mock function. Then, you call mockImplementation inside the test body in different test suits to setup the right return value.